# solana web3 confirmTransaction @deprecated using a TransactionConfirmationConfig example

Tags: typescript, solana, solana-web3js

With this code VS show a deprecated warning:

> (method) Connection.confirmTransaction(strategy: string, commitment?:
> Commitment): Promise<RpcResponseAndContext> (+1
> overload) @deprecated — Instead, call confirmTransaction using a
> TransactionConfirmationConfig
>
> The signature '(strategy: string, commitment?: Commitment):
> Promise<RpcResponseAndContext>' of
> 'connection.confirmTransaction' is deprecated

```
const airDropSol = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      publicKey,
      2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Could anyone make me an example with the new syntax, please?

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!

Comment: Sadly it looks like [the docs still use the deprecated method too](https://solanacookbook.com/references/local-development.html#getting-test-sol).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The new method signature looks like

```
confirmTransaction(
  strategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy,
  commitment?: Commitment,
): Promise<RpcResponseAndContext<SignatureResult>>;
```

So instead of earlier `TransactionSignature` it now expects `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy`

where

```
type BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
    signature: string;
} & Readonly<{
    blockhash: string;
    lastValidBlockHeight: number;
}>
```

Hence what you need is

```
  const airDropSol = async () => {
    try {
      const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
      const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        keypair.publicKey,
        2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
      );

      const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: airdropSignature,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hey. If you haven't already done so, please commit to the Solana Stackexchange. area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126615/solana You could greatly help us reach our goal!

Answer (score 0):

I little late answer, but this worked for me:

await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature: airdropSignature});